# node.js https server not rendering app pages

Tags: node.js, https, server

I just set up my local https server. However, when I go to my site `https://localhost:3001` or any pages like `/home` or /`projects`, the page does not render. Can someone help? Here is my code:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var https_port = 3001;

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./security/keys/localhost.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./security/keys/localhost.crt')
};

var a = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  console.log('https server works!); //this prints out properly
}).listen(https_port);
```

Comment: You just have to write res.render('soourceFileToBeRendered');
or you can check res.end('hello world\n');

Answer (score 0):

You should use a router to tell your server what to do with paths like `/home` or `/projects`.

```
var router = require('router');

router.get('/home', function(req, res){
res.send('This is home')
}
```

Comment: Hi - I already have a router that routes to all my pages... which worked fine when i created a regular http server, but the https server is giving me issues..